# Overlapping different year NDVI Map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, band, composite

I have created a NDVI time-series map for 5 different years. Now I want to prepare a combined raster band of the 5 years' time interval to form a single combined raster band.

How can this be done in ArcMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an image composite of five years NDVI data you can use the *Composite Bands* tool in ArcGIS.

Go to Data Management > Raster > Raster Processing > Composite Bands. Double-click the Composite Bands Tool. For input features, add all NDVI raster layers.

**EDIT:** I think you want all the raster bands to be in a single band. The *Composite Band* tool just overlays one layer after another creating a multi-band raster. If you want a single NDVI band, you can use the [*Cell Statistics*](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool. The tool uses a particular statistics of each corresponding cells in a composite raster.

You can use the tool to create a mean, sum, median or any other statistical function according to the requirements. You can add the composite raster as the input or just add the NDVI bands as input bands in the tool.

Comment: @That worked well; but the value was found different for the CB thus formed. The composite band thus formed shows different range of value for band with total band showing from B1 to B5. Thus, in this case, which Band shows the true value of NDVI.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand the problem.

Comment: @The result created a composite band but the composite band on checking symbology showed 5 band with different values. Thus, in this case which band shows the true value of NDVI for composite band.

Comment: @Pushkar I have edited my answer.

Comment: That worked well but the value is rendered between High : 3.27219e+08 and Low : -2.76656e+09 but the mean pixel value should be obtained between 0 and 1. How can this be solved???

Comment: @Pushkar did you check the ranges of all your NDVI values? Do all of them have ranges between -1- and 1?