# Different Band Values For NDVI Calculation For Composite Band

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, band, composite

I created composite map using individual NDVI map of Landsat-8 from 5 years. However, I am confused with the NDVI value rendered after creating composite map. I got different values of NDVI for different bands such as:

[image]

[image]

Thus, in this case what should I need to do that becomes the true representative value of NDVI?

Comment: Each NDVI band will have different range of values depending on the min-max range of the bands. Composite bands are just putting one layer after another. You have mentioned the same thing in this post [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462478/overlapping-different-year-ndvi-map-using-arcmap). Kindly stick to the question.